# How to update apps which are not on google play, i store or windows store

Tags: android, ios, django, windows, phonegap-build

Am making an app for our company. This is a specific app only for internal use. Its size will be around 200 -250 mb. It is a cross platform app (Using phone-gap), i.e., it will be active on windows, android and on apple. Am not putting it on any store, i.e., istore, wondows store or google play.

**Problem** : I want to create a way in which this app can be updated from server, i.e., every time I make some data changes to it, it should be updated  or ask for update on the respective platform.

**Possible Solution** : Use Django as a back-end. Every-time some data changes are saved, a script is initiated. This script updates or changes the respective code bases and builds the respective platforms. How can I push or pull these changes or updated version on the mobile devices?

Comment: You could use some form of push notifications, i.e. GCM, sent from your webapp every time you have an update. Simpler to just send an email when an update's ready though

Comment: @Cornholio : yes that can be a solution for android. Also will the solution I have suggested work ? Cause this is just a guess that I am putting up. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You'd probably need to use GCM, like I said, to let the app know there's an update, or else have it check periodically. Your solution should be fine, but either the app needs to check for updates or you need to tell it about them.

Answer (score 2):

PhoneGap offers [Hydration](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CD0QFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fbuild.phonegap.com%2Fdocs%2Fhydration&ei=TMVRUdfIFaS90AH7n4GwBQ&usg=AFQjCNFaMbm-QxdeJJYxt0369ICw9xDPGA&bvm=bv.44158598,d.dmQ), an automatic updating system activated by clicking a check-box.

It's more develoment than production oriented, but if this is an internal product, this would be a zero-cost solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use GCM for notifying the app, that you have an update.